# Finding a value within a range(condition) in each array of values in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

So, i have a data set where each row contains an array of values ranging from 0-600 which will eventually extend till the end of the sheet. [It looks something like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbLmA.png)
I'm trying to find the value that is within 100 and 200 then display it in the first column. Currently I'm using a FILTER Function in this format:

```
=FILTER(H2:BI2, H2:BI2 > 100, H2:BI2 < 200)
```

This returns results as expected for each row. However, I would like to use an array formula to apply it to the entire column which I did so in this format:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(FILTER(H2:BI, H2:BI > 100, H2:BI < 200))
```

However, this does not work with an error message "FILTER range must be a single row or a single column.". What's the best way to solve this? Thanks in advance.

[EDIT : My data is a controlled set of data where only one of the values will be within that range. If in rare cases two values appear, it can be ignored or just select the first one.]

Comment: `=FILTER()` is an array formula by definition so enclosing it in `ARRAYFORMULA()` won't work. Are you certain that only one value will fit the criteria for each row?

Comment: `FILTER` does not work as an array formula, it is called only once and not every iteration. What do you mean by "I'm trying to find the value that is within 100 and 200 then display it in the first column."? Do you need the first value that satisfies the conditions? Or do you need them all? Your first formula gives you the row, and it might be only one if there is only one, but otherwise it will take more than one column.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mentioned, the incoming data is controlled, and will only output one value that is within that range. If there is more than one in rare cases, the row can be ignored or just allow it to display an error. I will make an edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you might have more than one value satisfying the conditions (for the only one in a row it also works) then this formula will give you the column with the first ones for every row:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  IFNA(INT(REGEXEXTRACT(
    TRANSPOSE(
      QUERY(
        TRANSPOSE(
          IF((H2:BI > 100) * (H2:BI < 200), H2:BI, "")
        ),
        ,
        COLUMNS(H2:BI)
      )
    ),
    "^\s*(\d+)"
  )))
)
```

[image]

**UPD**

If you are sure that there is no more than one value that satisfies the conditions, then you could also use this formula:

```
=TRANSPOSE(
  SPLIT(
    TEXTJOIN(
      "",
      True,
      {
        ARRAYFORMULA(IF((H2:BI > 100) * (H2:BI < 200), H2:BI, "")) ,
        {
          TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(",-", ROWS(H2:BI) - 1), "-", True, True)); ""
        }
      }
    ),
    ",",
    True,
    False
  )
)
```

There will be a number in a cell, or a cell will have `""` if there is no number in a row that is >100 and <200.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help again, however I do have another question if you don't mind. In another cell, I would like to count the number of values that is  <100, 200-300 and >400. I'm trying to modify the solution you gave me but having some trouble.

Comment: @Max row wise counting of the elements is quite different solution. Here is for the "200-300": `=MMULT(ARRAYFORMULA(--((H2:BI > 200) * (H2:BI < 300))), SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(H2:BI), 1, 1, 0))`. For "<100" change `(H2:BI > 200) * (H2:BI < 300)` to `H2:BI <100`, for ">400" - to `H2:BI > 400`.

Comment: That works great. If there anyway I can use an OR statement so I can count all of it into one cell?

Comment: @Max. Sure, just need to use + instead of OR as it does not work inside `ARRAYFORMULA`. Try this: `=MMULT(ARRAYFORMULA(--(((H2:BI > 200) * (H2:BI < 300)) + (H2:BI < 100) + (H2:BI > 400)), SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(H2:BI), 1, 1, 0)))`

Comment: I copied it but i think there is some format error, i tried to fix but it returns some weird values back. I created a [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ey5h6Lp8Kk46_GSNJNMNO82pp1gFvFEqhjHWjYrT8Fw/edit?usp=sharing) to a shared sheet to test it. The red values are the values im trying to count for each row.

Comment: @Max Added check for empty string. `=MMULT(ARRAYFORMULA(--((H:BI <> "") * (((H:BI > 200) * (H:BI < 300)) + (H:BI < 100) + (H:BI > 400)))), SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(H:BI), 1, 1, 0))` Otherwise it returns `True` for `< 100`. See `Test1` sheet, formula is at `B1`.

Comment: Works great. Thanks again